# How to INSERT the continuous Date in HANA with SQL statement?

Tags: sql, hana, hana-sql-script

I have to insert the data like as below from 01-01-2018 to 31-12-2018.

```
insert into "schema"."tablename" (FISCAL_DATE,FISCAL_DT,REGION_CD,FISCAL_REGION_CD,FISCAL_DATE1,NEW_REGION_CD) values ('2018-01-01', '2018-01-01','EMEA','EUR','01/01/2018', 'EURO'); 
insert into "schema"."tablename" (FISCAL_DATE,FISCAL_DT,REGION_CD,FISCAL_REGION_CD,FISCAL_DATE1,NEW_REGION_CD) values ('2018-01-01', '2018-01-01','EMEA','EUR','01/01/2018', 'EURO'); 
insert into "schema"."tablename" (FISCAL_DATE,FISCAL_DT,REGION_CD,FISCAL_REGION_CD,FISCAL_DATE1,NEW_REGION_CD) values ('2018-01-01', '2018-01-01','EMEA','EUR','01/01/2018', 'EURO'); 
insert into "schema"."tablename" (FISCAL_DATE,FISCAL_DT,REGION_CD,FISCAL_REGION_CD,FISCAL_DATE1,NEW_REGION_CD) values ('2018-01-01', '2018-01-01','EMEA','EUR','01/01/2018', 'EURO');
...
insert into "schema"."tablename" (FISCAL_DATE,FISCAL_DT,REGION_CD,FISCAL_REGION_CD,FISCAL_DATE1,NEW_REGION_CD) values ('2018-12-31', '2018-12-31','EMEA','EUR','12/31/2018', 'EURO');
```

Is there any alternative SQL statements to achieve this or else need to go with manually update the dates one by one.

Please share your inputs/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to insert multiple records (day by day) with dates from `2018-01-01` to `2018-12-31`. 
You can achieve this using `WHILE` statement.

```
DO 
BEGIN

    DECLARE INPUT_DATE date := '2018-01-01';


    WHILE INPUT_DATE <= '2018-12-31'  DO

        INSERT INTO "schema"."tablename" (FISCAL_DATE,FISCAL_DT,REGION_CD,FISCAL_REGION_CD,FISCAL_DATE1,NEW_REGION_CD) values (:INPUT_DATE, :INPUT_DATE,'EMEA','EUR',:INPUT_DATE, 'EURO');

        INPUT_DATE = ADD_DAYS(:INPUT_DATE,1);

    END WHILE;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [SQL dates table on HANA database](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-dates-table-using-sqlscript-on-sap-hana-database.aspx) and it is very easy to create using SQLScript.

Please check following example (please replace table name and column names according to your model)

```
do
begin

declare date_start date := '01.01.2018';
declare date_end date := '31.12.2018';

insert into mySampleTransactionData (tdate)
SELECT generated_period_start
 FROM SERIES_GENERATE_DATE('INTERVAL 1 DAY', :date_start, add_days(:date_end,1));

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully inserted data with the below Query.

```
insert into "Schema"."tablename" (select to_nvarchar(gen_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as fiscal_date,
       to_nvarchar(gen_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as fiscal_dt,
       'AMR' as region_cd,
       'AMR' as fiscal_region_cd,
       to_nvarchar(gen_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as fiscal_date1,
       'AMR' as led_region_cd
from (
  select generated_period_start as gen_date from SERIES_GENERATE_DATE ('INTERVAL 1 DAY', '2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
));
```

Thank You all for your valuable suggestions!!